# How to delete Xcode created provisioning profile and create new?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, distribution, provisioning-profile

I am using Xcode 7 latest available, i've  created an provisioning profile for my project from xcode. It works perfectly fine while development but now i have to distribute my app so i login to my dev account and tried to make provis prof. but neither dev portal allowing me to make one nor it is present in the list.I've tried deleting the xcode generated one but it no effect in dev portal. Also, then i removed my account from xcode and readded the profile was still there.

If anyone can please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

First check in your Keychain Access in your mac.If it is present delete it . In developer Account revoke the certificates which are not necessary .

Comment: Its not about the developers certificate, my problem is that i have created Provisioning Profile through xcode and now i am unable to find it on my developers account and also i am unable to create the Provisioning Profile with same name